# Coredata bound NSNumber column on tableview crashes when attempting to edit

Tags: xcode, core-data, tableview, nsvaluetransformer

I have created (without coding) a coredata entity and a cocoa window that displays the rows in an editable tableview that is bound to an array controller bound to the entity. There is one NSNumber column in the table, which without a custom value transformer crashes on editing because the column form the tableview tries to save as a string.

So I created a custom value transformer which i linked to that column but i now get different errors. Here is my code:

```
#import "StringToNumberTransformer.h"  
@implementation StringToNumberTransformer  

+ (Class)transformedValueClass { return [NSNumber class]; }  

+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation { return NO; }  

- (id)transformedValue:(id)value {  

    NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];  
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];  
    NSNumber * _menuId = [f numberFromString:[value stringValue]];  

    return _menuId;  
}  
@end
```

Here is the error i get as soon as i click on the column:

```
[EntityName stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100137de0
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff876dbb06 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff836593f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8777240a -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 186
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff876ca02e ___forwarding___ + 414
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff876c9e18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
    5   ClickerData                         0x0000000100001439 -[StringToNumberTransformer transformedValue:] + 153
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a556612 -[NSBinder valueForBinding:atIndex:resolveMarkersToPlaceholders:] + 528
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a6bb947 -[NSEditableBinder editableStateAtIndex:] + 80
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a83bc2b -[NSTableBinder tableView:shouldEditTableColumn:row:] + 168
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a94f2b7 -[_NSBindingAdaptor tableView:shouldEditTableColumn:row:] + 157
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a849cd1 -[NSTableView _userCanEditTableColumn:row:] + 65
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a849dad -[NSTableView _userCanSelectAndEditTableColumn:row:] + 97
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a851ec8 -[NSTableView _shouldEditColumn:row:withEvent:] + 121
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a854861 -[NSTableView mouseDown:] + 5858
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a44250e -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 6853
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a43e644 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 5761
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a35421a -[NSApplication run] + 636
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a2f8bd6 NSApplicationMain + 869
    18  ClickerData                         0x0000000100002bf2 main + 34
    19  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff842be7e1 start + 0
    20  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
```

What am i doing wrong here? I just want to be able to enter a number and let it save back to the entity.
Many thanks

Comment: change return type as NSNumber.                                   NSNumber * _menuId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[value intValue]]; and return the _menuId.

Comment: You should check what kind of object `value` is. Either set a breakpoint in the debugger or NSLog `value` and `[value class]`.

Comment: Thank you I have tried everything and even changed it to a look more like the apple documentation suggests. I see I would need a reverse transformer and also i realised my transformer should take in NSNumber and return String , not the other way around as i had it. I still can't get it to work though! I can't add the code and can't add a new comment argh. Will add the code later as a reply when my 4 hour limit is up.